# FileNotFoundException loading image from SD card pathway

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception

I am attempting to load a image from SD card/device memory by opening a file taking a string representing the pathway as a argument:

```
File imagePathFile = new File(savedImapthPathwayOnPause);
        try {

            final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 3000;
            FileInputStream streamIn = new FileInputStream(imagePathFile);

            // important to reduce size of image before it is loaded into memory
            // and then resized, otherwise will
            // get out of memory error

            // Decode image size and setInJBounds = true to avoid auto memory
            // allocation for large image
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(streamIn, null, o);
            streamIn.close();

            //by setting m.pow(scale, 3.85) we get a org image of 2500:1400 beofre loaded and when loaded we get 426:240, no need fro resize method call here
            int scale = 1;
            while ((o.outWidth * o.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 3.73)) > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
                scale++;
            }

            // get orginal width of image before loaded into memory
            Log.d("VIEW DIVE", "scale = " + scale + ", orig-width: " + o.outWidth
                    + "  orig-height: " + o.outHeight);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Orginal Image size from DB: width: "+ o.outWidth + "/height: " + o.outHeight , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Bitmap b = null;
            streamIn = new FileInputStream(imagePathFile);
            if (scale > 1) {
                scale--;
                // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
                // larger than target, inSampleSize loads the image into memor
                // by a factor of its integer value
                o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inSampleSize = scale;
                // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(streamIn, null, o);
                //makeToast("Image after sacling and now loading: width: "+ o.outWidth + "/height: " + o.outHeight );
                //resizedImage = reSizeImage(b); this is blowing uo and alreadt samll image from
                //org size 2500:1400 to 73:44, then blown back up in resize does not look good

                streamIn.close();
                //b.recycle();
                System.gc();
```

But I keep getting the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)  at
java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)     at
com.mooney.diveapp.LogDive.setImageViewFromSavedInstance(LogDive.java:198)
    at com.mooney.diveapp.LogDive.onCreate(LogDive.java:134)    at
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255)      at
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
```

EDIT: How the image path string is set requested (done in a asycnh inner class):

```
// check if external storage is available to write
            Bitmap imageToSave = params[0];// get image

            final String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                // media available
                canSaveToExternalSD = true;
                // use a random number to append to image file name until use
                // diveNumber according to log entry on
                Random diveNum = new Random();
                File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                final File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()
                        + File.separator + diveAlbum);
                final File theFile = new File(directory, "image"
                        + diveNum.nextInt(5000) + ".png");
                directory.getParentFile().mkdirs();

                if (!directory.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Directory not created!!!!");
                }

                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(theFile);
                    imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();

//assign path to a string
savedImagePath = theFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

Later in the code the saveImagePath is assigned to savedImapthPathwayOnPause.

EDIT: Expand on later in code.
So when user navigate away form activity A by calling either a Goggle Maps or Facebookpost activity from within Activity B, I saved the string savedImagePath in onSavedINstance State.

Then when user returns too activity A I get the savedIMagePathway back in on create, and pass this to the method posted above File imagePathFile = new File(savedImagePathwayOnPause) posted above.

The values of savedImagePathwayOnPause at this time is: /storage/emulated/0/dive_photos/image2588.png

However, sometimes this value returns empty (to its initialised state = ""). This appears to be random...as some times works and not others...

```
@Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

            //if onPause called on activity when user selects maps or FB, we lose value of global varibles like 
            //saveIMageBPath and photoBitMap but keep all view values (Edittexts)
            //so we must save our global values here and call them back on onRestoreInstance state and assign to IMageButton

            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);


           outState.putString("savedImapthPathwayOnSaveInstance", savedImagePath);
        }
```

and in onCreate():

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore value of members from saved state
           // mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE); 
            this.savedImapthPathwayOnPause = savedInstanceState.getString("savedImapthPathwayOnSaveInstance");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "on returning the image path is : " + savedImapthPathwayOnPause, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //no we ust get the bitmap form the image path and return to IMageView
            Log.d("MYTAG", "on returning the image path is : " + savedImapthPathwayOnPause);

            if(!savedImapthPathwayOnPause.isEmpty())
            setImageViewFromSavedInstance(savedImapthPathwayOnPause);
            Log.d("MYTAG", "on returning the image path not found:==  " + savedImapthPathwayOnPause);
        }
```

Comment: The exception indicates that you are trying to open the root directory, likely because you provide an effectively empty (or perhaps even null?) path.  Log what your path string actually is, and figure out why it is not what you expect it to be.  That problem is not in the posted code.

Comment: "Later in the code" doesn't give much information, especially when you say there's async code at play. If the code that selects the file path runs concurrent to the code that uses it, you could find yourself trying to use `savedImapthPathwayOnPause` before it's been assigned - which would explain the issue. If this isn't the case, you should post all relevant code in its context (classes, functions, etc.)

Comment: hmmmm the issue is the synch task takes a few seconds to set the savedImagePathwayOnPause...if another activity is called before this is set a empty string is passed to the File....

Answer (score 0):

As @Paf suggested the issue was the image path was been generated in a synch class, so if the File open was called before the path was generated I was passing a empty string to the File constructor.

To avoid this I disabled any calls to creation of the File by disabling Buttons that did so in on Pre-Exceute and Enabled them again in onPostExceute methods of Aynsch inner class AFTER the String file path was generated.

Thanks